# Codeigniter setflash data wont clear after refresh

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, flash-message, codeigniter-query-builder

[image]

hi everyone who had an idea on how to clear the `setflashdata?` im just new at codeigniter Framework.

This is my Controller view that has the submit function and view for the page add view

**Controller:-**

```
 public function add(){
            $this->load->view('layout/header');
            $this->load->view('blog/add');
            $this->load->view('layout/footer');
        }
    
        public function submit(){
            $result = $this->m->submit();
            if($result){
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', 'Record added successfully');
            }else{
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg', 'Faill to add record');
            }
            redirect(base_url('blog/index'));
        }
```

This is the view html page for the datable and add record button.

```
 <h3>Blog list</h3>
    
        <?php
            if($this->session->flashdata('success_msg')){
        ?>
            <div class="alert alert-success alert-status">
                <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success_msg'); ?>
            </div>
        <?php       
            }
        ?>
    
    
        <?php
            if($this->session->flashdata('error_msg')){
        ?>
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('error_msg'); ?>
            </div>
        <?php       
            }
        ?>
```

//this is the button that has the add function.

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('blog/add'); ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Add New</a>
```

**This is the datatable view**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ID</td>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Created at</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
```

/this function will fetch the datas coming from your database.

```
<?php 
                    if($blogs){
                        foreach($blogs as $blog){
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $blog->id; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $blog->title; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $blog->description; ?></td
                    </tr>
                <?php
                        }
                    }
                ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: have your problem is solved or not??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a CodeIgniter issue.

For your problem solution use below view

**View:**

```
<?php
if ($this->session->flashdata ( 'success' )) {
    ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success"> 
    <?php  echo $this->session->flashdata('success'); ?>
    <?php
    $this->session->unset_userdata ( 'success' );
} else if ($this->session->flashdata ( 'error' )) {
    ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
    <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('error'); ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    $this->session->unset_userdata ( 'error' );
}
?>
```

Comment: i just had tried it but no flash data is showing after i add a record

Comment: how about i want to remove the java script it is possible?

Comment: Where is Javscript?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>assets/js/jquery.min.js" ></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" rel="stylesheet"> 
$('document').ready(function(){
 $(".alert").fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(5000);
 });
 </script>  this one

Comment: that script after 5-second automatic alert box hides if you don't want to hide then remove that script. and when you page refresh or moves to another screen then alert box automatically hide.

Comment: i had try to remove it but what happen is the setflash wont display but when i put the script it will display in 1 seconds and disappear in 5 seconds

Comment: style="display:none" remove check update answer

Comment: This worked for me, add a set_userdata after displaying the alert.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this in your View:-**

```
<?php 
    if($this->session->flashdata('success')){
    ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success"  style="display:none;"> 
    <?php  echo $this->session->flashdata('success'); ?>
    <?php    
    } else if($this->session->flashdata('error')){
    ?>
    <div class = "alert alert-danger"  style="display:none;">
    <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('error'); ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Put this in your before end `</body>` Tag View:-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>assets/js/jquery.min.js" ></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" rel="stylesheet"> 
$('document').ready(function(){
 $(".alert").fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(5000);
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: i had tried it but after fading i try to refresh it shows a flashdata again.